# Getting ORA-10028 with DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT even with small chunk size?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to get a DBMS_OUTPUT that has an extensive length (60K+ characters). I understand the limit is 32767, but the issue for me with using the common LOOP solution...

```
LOOP
EXIT WHEN OUTPUT_OFFSET > DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(VAROUTT);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(VAROUTT, OUTPUT_CHUNKS, OUTPUT_OFFSET));
    OUTPUT_OFFSET := OUTPUT_OFFSET + OUTPUT_CHUNKS;
END LOOP;
```

... is that my string already contains new lines based on the calculation that is being done within the procedure. With PUT_LINE I'm getting the following (yellow) due to the PUT_LINE size:

[image]

So I need to make use of PUT, to ensure it's my procedure the one that determines when a NEW_LINE is to be inserted. I tried the following:

```
LOOP
EXIT WHEN OUTPUT_OFFSET > DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(VAROUTT);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(VAROUTT, OUTPUT_CHUNKS, OUTPUT_OFFSET));
    OUTPUT_OFFSET := OUTPUT_OFFSET + OUTPUT_CHUNKS;
END LOOP;
```

The only difference is that I'm calling command "PUT" instead of "PUT_LINE", to prevent my output from performing irrelevant new-line calls. The issue is that I'm getting error:

```
ORU-10028: line length overflow, limit of 32767 bytes per line.
```

This happens only if I use PUT instead of PUT_LINE, even if my chunk size is 10. My initial setup is:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE UNLIMITED;
SET LINESIZE 200;
```

Not sure if the LINESIZE setup is relevant, still 200 is bigger than 10. Each line doesn't surpass 50 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LINESIZE` is a sqlplus parameter that wraps text in the display; it has no bearing on PL/SQL code.

By [definition](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_OUTPUT.html#GUID-1BCA24ED-0799-4ACA-9FB1-4CEC24FE41E7), `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT` "places a partial line in the buffer." It doesn't matter how you set up your chunk size because you're just appending into the same 32K line limit. You must call `DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE` or `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` to introduce separate lines.

Note that `DBMS_OUTPUT` is generally used for debugging messages, and not large-scale text reporting.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing a print at each line, which at the end was not that bad (performance).

Answer (score 0):

> my string already contains new lines

You can split your string on those newline characters (assuming each of those lines is then less than 32k, which seems to be the case - you said they're less than 50 characters each); i.e. varying `OUTPUT_CHUNKS` each time, and reading each chunk (minus its own newline) into a string buffer that you then print with `put_line()`. Something like:

```sql
...
BUFFER varchar2(32767);
...
WHILE OUTPUT_OFFSET < DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(VAROUTT) LOOP
  -- read to next newline if there is one, rest of CLOB if not
  IF dbms_lob.instr(VAROUTT, chr(10), OUTPUT_OFFSET) > 0 then
    OUTPUT_CHUNKS := dbms_lob.instr(VAROUTT, chr(10), OUTPUT_OFFSET) - OUTPUT_OFFSET;
    dbms_lob.read(VAROUTT, OUTPUT_CHUNKS, OUTPUT_OFFSET, BUFFER);
    OUTPUT_OFFSET := OUTPUT_OFFSET + OUTPUT_CHUNKS + 1; -- skip newline character
  ELSE
    OUTPUT_CHUNKS := 32767;
    dbms_lob.read(VAROUTT, OUTPUT_CHUNKS, OUTPUT_OFFSET, BUFFER);
    OUTPUT_OFFSET := OUTPUT_OFFSET + OUTPUT_CHUNKS;
  END IF;

  dbms_output.put_line(BUFFER);
END LOOP;
```

You could store `DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(VAROUTT)` in a variable to avoid recalculating that thousands of times.